# How to ignore @Filter marked entity class with CreateQuery

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

One java entity class added `@Filter`.

While using entity class with hibernate service, all queries will add the filter with where condition. I need to ignore this for one case. I mean:

```
entityManager.CreateQuery("SELECT * from ABCTABLE where tenant_id=9999");
```

In above query i added common filter `tenant_id` and that common filter i have to ignore for above query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable/disable filters using `Session.enableFilter(String filterName)` and `Session.disableFilter(String filterName)`. So you can disable the filter before executing the query and enable it afterwards. Keep in mind that `EntityManager` does not support this, so you have access the Hibernate session, for example:

```
((Session)entityManager.getDelegate()).disableFilter(filterName);
```

Comment: hi while using disable filter also it is giving error. like org.hibernate.HibernateException: Filter [tenant] parameter [tenant_id] value not set

Comment: I can't comment on this without seeing your code. I suggest you ask another question with the relevant code and stack trace.